# Views Table with Aggregation, total values counted per option

Tags: views

I'm setting up a view of event registrations. Each registration will be allocated to 1 of 3 workshops at two different times in the day.

I'm looking to output the total number of allocations per workshop so we can try to balance the delegate numbers.

I'm pretty close, but not quite there.

I'm using the Display Format of Table with aggregation options with "Group and Compress" on the Event ID.

I then apply the group function on two data fields:
"Allocated Workshop AM" and "Allocated Workshop PM".

I can get closest to my desired result using the "Tally members" option, however, the results are wrong.

[image]

They are showing much lower numbers than are actually allocated.

[image]

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?